# How do I validate JSON data - with full error report - using the jsweet::is-my-json-valid candy?

Tags: javascript, json, validation

I'm working on a Javascript project and use the JSweet framework for writing the Javascript part. As part of it's function, my application will asynchronously load some JSON data (stored as separate file). I would like to validate that data using a JSON schema validator. JSweet offers several such validators, one of which is a port of 'is-my-json-valid' (original Javascript library in https://github.com/mafintosh/is-my-json-valid, JSweet port in http://public.jsweet.org/apidocs/releases/org/jsweet/candies/is-my-json-valid).

I am already able to use the is-my-json-valid library to give me a true/false indication of whether a given JSON chunk conforms to a given JSON schema. However, in case of a failing validation, I would also like to retrieve error details as to why it failed (e.g. 'required attribute blah').

How would I have to use the is-my-json-valid library in JSweet so I get more than a true/false indication - i.e. I am also getting a full report telling me what was wrong with my JSON data?

Here is my JSweet test program. The transpiled Javascript already throws the exception correctly - the only thing that would gladden my heart is a detailed error report:

```
package json_valid.test_01;

import static def.is_my_json_valid.Globals.is_my_json_valid;

import jsweet.lang.Error;
import jsweet.lang.JSON;

public class Test_01
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String              sSchema;
        String              sTestFail;
        String              sTestPass;

        sSchema     =
            "{\n"
            + "  \"required\": true,\n"
            + "  \"type\": \"object\",\n"
            + "  \"properties\": {\n"
            + "    \"hello\": {\n"
            + "      \"required\": true,\n"
            + "      \"type\": \"string\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  }\n"
            + "}\n";
        sTestFail       = "{\"a\": \"b\"}";
        sTestPass       = "{\"hello\": \"world\"}";
        _AssertConforms (sTestPass, sSchema);   /* Ok - expect nothing printed to console  */
        _AssertConforms (sTestFail, sSchema);   /* AiaOw - expect error message on console */
    }

    private static void _AssertConforms (String jsonData, String jsonSchema)
    {
        Object              oSchema;
        Object              oTested;
        boolean             result;
        String              specifics;
        String              message;

        oTested = JSON.parse (jsonData);
        oSchema = JSON.parse (jsonSchema);
        result = is_my_json_valid (oSchema).apply (oTested);
        if (! result)
        {
            specifics = "Sorry, still waiting for that nifty code to extract error specifics from is-my-json-valid.";
            message   = "Validation failed. Error specifics: " + specifics;
            throw new Error (message);
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML test page is rather boring:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>JSON validator test</title>
<script src="../../../target/dist/bundle-test_01.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I load the page into my Chrome web browser, the web console provides me with an exception as expected:

```
bundle-test_01.js:1535 Uncaught Error: Validation failed. Error specifics: Sorry, still waiting for that nifty code to extract error specifics from is-my-json-valid.
    Test_01._AssertConforms @ bundle-test_01.js:1535
    Test_01.main @ bundle-test_01.js:1521
    12.is-my-json-valid @ bundle-test_01.js:1541
    s @ bundle-test_01.js:1
    e @ bundle-test_01.js:1
    (anonymous function) @ bundle-test_01.js:1
```

All I am missing is the error details in the exception message.

Thank you so much for your consideration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the current version of JSweet doesn't yet work together with the is-my-json-valid  component. From the JSweet author:

> Ok. I have bad news.
>
> I took a closer look to is-my-json-valid, and it seems that it is only
>   provided as a node module. That wouldn't be an issue and in theory,
>   you would just need to compile with the "module" option. However, it
>   seems that the way the module is defined is not supported yet by
>   JSweet. It looks like JSweet cannot require properly the module, as it
>   is specified here: https://github.com/mafintosh/is-my-json-valid.
>
> In general, before using a module, it is good to know if it can be
>   used from the browser, because node modules are still only partially
>   supported in JSweet.
>
> The good news is that is-my-json-valid seems to be the perfect use
>   case that I was looking for to improve JSweet's requires, as already
>   discussed in #129. So I will be working on it ASAP.

See https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet/issues/144